# Unbiased estimate of the standard deviation of multiple sample means

Tags: variance, sample

I want to know the volatility of a particular variable over time. Specifically, I'm looking at the volatility of the annual growth rate in compute (FLOPs) used by large ML models. I have a database of published ML models (from [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AAIebjNsnJj_uKALHbXNfn3_YsT6sHXtCU0q7OIPuc4/edit#gid=0)), each with a date and compute used. For each year, I can take the average compute of all models from that year, calculate the growth rate of this average, and then find the standard deviation of all the growth rates.

Specifically, the thing I'm calculating is $\text{SD}_t[\bar{x}_{t+1} / \bar{x}_t - 1]$ where $\bar{x}_t$ is the mean of all samples in year t.

But this number is biased upward because I don't know the true mean for each year, I only know the mean of a particular sample. **Is there an unbiased formula (or at least a better formula) for the volatility of the growth rate?**

Note: The thing I want is related to [pooled variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance), but pooled variance gives the variance within each sample, and I want to know the variance across samples.

One formula that seems plausibly good is `standard deviation of means – pooled standard error`, but I don't have any mathematical justification for that.